# Click on many of the same buttons when scraping data

Tags: r, web-scraping, google-play, rvest, rselenium

I'm trying to scrape reviews from this Google Play site using R (manily "RSelenium" and "rvest":
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hr.mireo.arthur&hl=en&fbclid=IwAR3c-PkUXOea8KrKLp9Q3JUjCidGmgO2jYX_Qb7O8VuWlHXPIS5nDOfKRKI&showAllReviews=true

I've managed to load page using RSelenium and make a loop which scrolls down the page and clicks on all "Show more" buttons. Here is the code I've used:

```
#Load packages
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(wdman)
library(RSelenium)

#Open website using RSelenium
url <- 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hr.mireo.arthur&hl=en&fbclid=IwAR3c-PkUXOea8KrKLp9Q3JUjCidGmgO2jYX_Qb7O8VuWlHXPIS5nDOfKRKI&showAllReviews=true'
rD <- rsDriver(port = 4567L, browser=c("chrome"), chromever="80.0.3987.106")
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url)

#Load whole page by scrolling and showing more
xp_show_more <- "//*[@id='fcxH9b']/div[4]/c-wiz/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div"
replicate(5,
          {
            replicate(5,
                      {
                        # scroll down
                        webElem <- remDr$findElement("css", "body")
                        webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "end"))
                        # wait
                        Sys.sleep(1)
                      })
            # find button
            morereviews <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', xp_show_more)
            # click button
            tryCatch(morereviews$clickElement(),error=function(e){print(e)}) # trycatch to prevent any error from stopping the loop
            # wait
            Sys.sleep(3)
          })
```

This results with loading all 573 comments, but several comments have "Full review" buttons which have to be clicked in order to see the rest of it. I'm trying to make a script which clicks on all "Full review" buttons (I beleave there are just over 30 of them), but I can't manage to do so. My current script clicks on the first "Full review" buttons

```
#Click on "Full Review"
xp_full_review <- '//*[@id="fcxH9b"]/div[4]/c-wiz/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/span[1]/div/button'
replicate(35,
          {
fullreviews <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', xp_full_review)
fullreviews$clickElement()
Sys.sleep(0.5)
          })
```

Can someone spot a mistake and find a way to click on all "Full review" buttons?

Thank you

Comment: Aren't you just using the same xpath every time in your loop? Why would that click on different buttons?

Comment: Than is there a way to somehow select all buttons of the same type and click on all of them?
Though, when I check other "Full review" buttons, they all have the sam xpath. That's why I thought that using one xpath will be ok.